# Minimum Key Length for Apache SSL

Tags: apache-2.2, openssl, mod-ssl

I'm trying to figure out the `minimum key/cipher bit length` that my Apache `mod_ssl` configuration will accept for client connections.

I ran `openssl ciphers -v` and saw ciphers of all lengths (40, 56, etc.).

How can I find out or configure the minimum length key that Apache will accept?

In other words, if a client requests a connection with a cipher of bit length `40`, how can I specify that the connection should be refused since it's `< 64`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SSLRequire %{SSL_CIPHER_USEKEYSIZE} >= 128
```

This directive is treated as an access requirement and any connection that fails to meet this requirement will receive a 403 response.

Comment: Thank you, @Danila Ladner. For my own reference, I saw this link too: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2009867.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to point out that this `directive` needs to be applied to a `<Directory>` or `.htaccess`